# Intersecting planes stereometry problem

Tags: geometry

Two planes P and Q intersect at a line (e). From a random point A we draw a perpendicular line AB to the plane P and a perpendicular line AC to the plane Q.
We also draw perpendiculars from B and C to line (e). Prove that these two lines intersect.

Let's name O the intersection of the perpendicular from B to line (e) and R the intersection of the perpendicular from C to (e). 
The perpendicular from B to the line (e) lies completely on the plane P since (e) belongs to P. Also, since AB is perpendicular to plane P, it is perpendicular to any line of P that passes through B. Therefore AB is perpendicular to BO. Similarly AC is perpendicular to CR.

How do we proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the plane that is perpendicular to (e) and contains $A$, and show that it also contains $B$ and $C$.

Comment: Arthur thank you - what is "normal"? Sorry, solid geometry is completely unknown to me - I hardly know the very basics!!

Comment: @Sal.Cognato "Normal" and "orthogonal" and "perpendicular" are three words that (almost always) mean the same thing, and I'm not good at knowing when to use which. Sorry about that.

Comment: I think CO and BO form a plane perpendicular to (e) but how do we prove this plane contains A? (I took it the other way round!)